# Как правильно внести в array динамичные данные?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

впервые сталкиваюсь с такой проблемой, сижу уже 3+ часов и не могу понять как мне решить ее.

Заранее скажу, использую библиотеку RedBeanPHP и там должен быть код в таком формате:

```
R::getAll('select * from link where UserNick = :nick',
    array(':nick'=>$usrnick)
);
```

В чем суть: В скрипте есть всего 4 значения, для начала я начал работать с первыми двумя, там идёт Ник формата Dima_Dima (суть не важна какой формат), и IP адрес.
Если данные не пустые я вот этим скриптом формирую запрос и добавляю в array (`array($peremennaya)`):

```
function addArray($arrayadd, $add, $and = true) {
    if ($arrayadd) {
        if ($and) $arrayadd .= ", $add";
    }
    else $arrayadd = $add;
    return $arrayadd;
}
```

Итог получается такой (var_dump): `array(1) { [0]=> string(33) "":nickp"=>$plrnck, ":ipp"=>$plrip" }`

P.s - $plrnck - это переменная с ником, я специально сделал чтобы он писал именно ее, так что смогу вернуть чтобы писал ник.

Посидев и подумав я понял, что таким образом array тупо вносит весь текст под 0 не разбирая это на части.

Если сделать вручную то итог такой: `array(2) { [":nickp"]=> string(9) "Dima_Dima" [":ipp"]=> string(13) "111.111.111.111" }`

Так вот, как мне сделать, чтобы в array писалось как в ручном варианте?

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во втором случае это - ассоциативный массив. Чтоб добавить новых элементов:

```
$arrayadd[':ipp'] = $plrip;
```

или, если нужно добавить массив:

```
$arrayadd = array_merge($arrayadd, array(':ipp'=>$plrip));
```

если нужно обязательно создавать функцию, то:

```
function addArray(array $already_exists_array, array $array_to_add){
    if($array_to_add){
        return array_merge($already_exists_array,$array_to_add);
    }
    return $already_exists_array;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Это мне очень помогло, до этого я нашел костыльный метод который занимал во много раз больше кода, но твой гораздо меньше выходит. Спасибо еще раз ❤